# RCFile - emitting GZip compressed int columns

Tags: hadoop

For some reason, Hive is not recognizing columns emitted as integers, but does recognize columns emitted as strings.

Is there something about Hive or `RCFile` or GZ that is preventing proper rendering of int?

My Hive DDL looks like:

```
create external table if not exists db.table (intField int, strField string) stored as rcfile location '/path/to/my/data';
```

And the relevant portion of my Java looks like:

```
BytesRefArrayWritable dataWrite = new BytesRefArrayWritable(2);
byte[] byteArray;
BytesRefWritable bytesRefWritable = new BytesRefWritable();                             intWritable.set(myObj.getIntField());
byteArray = WritableUtils.toByteArray(intWritable.get());
bytesRefWritable.set(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
dataWrite.set(0, bytesRefWritable);  // sets int field as column 0


bytesRefWritable = new BytesRefWritable();
textWritable.set(myObj.getStrField());
bytesRefWritable.set(textWritable.getBytes(), 0, textWritable.getLength());
dataWrite.set(1, bytesRefWritable);  // sets str field as column 1
```

The code runs fine, and through logging I can see the various `Writables` have bytes within them.

Hive can read the external table as well, but the `int` field shows up as `NULL`, [indicating some error](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-types.html#LanguageManualTypes-HandlingofNULLValues).

```
SELECT * from db.table;

OK
NULL    my string field
Time taken: 0.647 seconds
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure exactly why this is the case, but I got it working using the following method:

In the code that writes the byte array representing the integer value, instead of using `WritableUtils.toByteArray()`, I instead `Text.set(Integer.toString(intVal)).getBytes()`.

In other words, I convert the integer to its `String` representation, and use the `Text` writable object to get the byte array as if it were a string.

Then, in my Hive DDL, I can call the column an `int` and it interprets it correctly.

I'm not sure what was initially causing the problem, be it a bug in `WritableUtils`, some incompatibility with compressed integer byte arrays, or a faulty understanding of how this stuff works on my part.  In any event, the solution described above successfully meets the task's needs.